# angular 4 can't access to json response

Tags: angular

I want to log some errors in some specific situation, if I try to log `error` I have:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "entity" : "Movement",
    "property" : "direction",
    "invalidValue" : null,
    "message" : "Il campo non può essere vuoto. Inserire un valore valido e ripetere loperazione."
  }, {
    "entity" : "Movement",
    "property" : "workSession",
    "invalidValue" : null,
    "message" : "Il campo non può essere vuoto. Inserire un valore valido e ripetere loperazione."
  }, {
    "entity" : "Movement",
    "property" : "description",
    "invalidValue" : null,
    "message" : "Il campo non può essere vuoto. Inserire un valore valido e ripetere loperazione."
  } ]
}
```

This is the full error log:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK", url: "http://79.1.33.138:8080/api/v1/movements", ok: false, …}
error:"{↵  "errors" : [ {↵    "entity" : "Movement",↵    "property" : "direction",↵    "invalidValue" : null,↵    "message" : "Il campo non può essere vuoto. Inserire un valore valido e ripetere loperazione."↵  }, { ↵    "entity" : "Movement",↵    "property" : "workSession",↵    "invalidValue" : null,↵    "message" : "Il campo non può essere vuoto. Inserire un valore valido e ripetere loperazione."↵  }, { ↵    "entity" : "Movement",↵    "property" : "description",↵    "invalidValue" : null,↵    "message" : "Il campo non può essere vuoto. Inserire un valore valido e ripetere loperazione."↵  } ]↵}"headers:HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}message:"Http failure response for http://79.1.33.138:8080/api/v1/movements: 400 OK"name:"HttpErrorResponse"ok:false status:400statusText:"OK" url:"http://...../api/v1/movements"  __proto__:HttpResponseBase
```

But if I try to log `error.errors` or `error.errors[0]` I see: `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`
What's wrong with this response, usually I don't have any problem like this

Comment: error.errors[0] should work

Comment: where are you trying to log in the template or component ?

Comment: @Sajeetharan I know

Comment: @RahulSingh in the component

Comment: can you try some thing like `error['error'][0]` or better build a model for the same

Comment: Try removing the "" from your keys and array: `{
  errors : [ {
    entity : "Movement",`

Also give the log of **error**

Comment: @RahulSingh `error['error'][0]` doesn't change

Comment: @Swoox but all the others responses are with "" and I have no problems

Comment: when u log `error` , what is the result ?

Comment: @Med_Ali_Rachid updated

Comment: @Alessandro Is it me or is error a string? `error:"{↵` can you `console.log(typeof error)` ?

Comment: Update your question with the code where you access to the error object, otherwise is imposible to know what are you doing

Comment: @Swoox does the chrome console parse it like a array?

Comment: @Alessandro yes 'a' will be printed as **a**. This is an array: `(2) [{…}, {…}]
0
:
{fieldname: "ID", show: "", value: "", datatype: "", readonly: false, …}
1
:
{fieldname: "", value: "", show: "", datatype: "", readonly: false, …}
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)`

Comment: @Swoox ok I see this is an HttpErrorResponse so is it normal that error is a string and not a Json

Comment: @Alessandro glad you found it.

Comment: @Swoox actually I am not sure about this,  HttpErrorResponse gives me always a string?

Comment: @Alessandro See my answer, I tested this in my own application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on all information with the comments I found a way to parse your string (error). You can convert your string into json with the parser it's providing:

```
JSON.parse(error);
```

Comment: Yes I need it because in this case HttpErrorResponse gives me a string, But always is giving me a string?

Comment: @Alessandro It depend on the backend but in this case yes.